# Plot first point in a different shape

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am doing a cluster visualization in the following way:

```
for k in range(0, n_clusters):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for j in range(0, len(final_cluster_result[k])):
        x_res = list(final_cluster_result[k][j].longitude)
        y_res = list(final_cluster_result[k][j].latitude)
        x.append(x_res)
        y.append(y_res)
    x = [s for t in x for s in t]
    y = [s for t in y for s in t]
    plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=3)
#     plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('Clusters',fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel("Longitude",fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel("Latitude",fontsize=15)
```

I want to plot every starting point of clusters/colors in a different shape (to understand where do the movements start)

[sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT3QG.jpg)

I want:
For blue color plot first point with a black dot with blue color
For rescolor plot first point with a black dot with red color
...

Comment: After `plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=3)` do `plt.plot([x[0]], [y[0]], 's', markersize=5)`?

Comment: I would just plot the first dot again in the format you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Quang-Hoang, pasting here for others filtering for questions without answers:

> After plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=3) do plt.plot([x[0]], [y[0]], 's', markersize=5)